# Bad Index when calling SAP RFC_READ_TABLE

Tags: vba, runtime-error, abap, saprfc

I keep getting bad index error for below code..

```
Sub GetDocumentedGoodsMovement()

    Dim funcs As SAPFunctions
    Dim ws As Worksheet        
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    Set sapConn = CreateSapFunctions()
    If sapConn Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set objRfcFunc = sapConn.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE")
    Set objQueryTab = objRfcFunc.Exports("QUERY_TABLE")
    Set objDelimiter = objRfcFunc.Exports("DELIMITER")
    Set objRowCount = objRfcFunc.Exports("ROWCOUNT")
    
    objRowCount.Value = "99999999"
    
    Set objOptTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("OPTIONS")
    Set objFldTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("FIELDS")
    Set objDatTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("DATA")
    
    objQueryTab.Value = "AUFM"  'TABLE
    objDelimiter.Value = "|"    'DELIMITER
    
    
    objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "AUFNR EQ '000009999999"' AND BWART EQ '261'"  'FILTERS FOR VIEW.
    objFldTab.FreeTable
    

    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "AUFNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "MBLNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "MATNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "LGORT"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.RAppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "BWART"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "SHKZG"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    

    
    If objRfcFunc.Call = False Then
        MsgBox objRfcFunc.Exception
    End If
    
    Dim objDatRec As Object
    Dim objFldRec As Object
    
    For Each objDatRec In objDatTab.Rows
        For Each objFldRec In objFldTab.Rows
            ws.Cells(objDatRec.Index + 1, objFldRec.Index) = Mid(objDatRec("WA"), objFldRec("OFFSET") + 1, objFldRec("LENGTH"))
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

**Error occurs at line:**

```
objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "AUFNR EQ '000009999999"' AND BWART EQ '261'"
```

**The error are as follows:**

```
"Run-time error '-2147352565 (8002000b)':
Bad index
```

Are there any pointers as to why this error occurs? The following breakdowns are already done to try to locate the source of the error (without any luck so far):

1. I have the required auth. to call RFC_READ_TABLE.
2. The value '000009999999' is correct, and exists in table AUFM.
3. There are entries for the given order number, with Movement type (BWART) 261.
4. The SAP Logon works as it should, without any errors.
5. I've tested the exact same entries in SE37. It gives me the result I'm after.

Comment: '000009999999 " ' => this looks like a typo (I put spaces in it, to be clear), the _"_ and the _'_ have to be replaced?

Comment: You are totally correct.. However, after changing to:
"AUFNR EQ '000009999999' AND BWART EQ '261' "

The error is still the same.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the error occured due to missing row in `objOptTab` .
To fix the error, I added this row:

```
objOptTab.AppendRow
```

**Complete, working code:**

```
Sub GetDocumentedGoodsMovement()

    Dim funcs As SAPFunctions
    Dim ws As Worksheet        
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    Set sapConn = CreateSapFunctions()
    If sapConn Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set objRfcFunc = sapConn.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE")
    Set objQueryTab = objRfcFunc.Exports("QUERY_TABLE")
    Set objDelimiter = objRfcFunc.Exports("DELIMITER")
    Set objRowCount = objRfcFunc.Exports("ROWCOUNT")
    
    objRowCount.Value = "99999999"
    
    Set objOptTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("OPTIONS")
    Set objFldTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("FIELDS")
    Set objDatTab = objRfcFunc.Tables("DATA")
    
    objQueryTab.Value = "AUFM"  'TABLE
    objDelimiter.Value = "|"    'DELIMITER
    
    objOptTab.AppendRow
    objOptTab(objOptTab.RowCount, "TEXT") = "AUFNR EQ '000009999999' AND BWART EQ '261'"  'FILTERS FOR VIEW.
    objFldTab.FreeTable
    

    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "AUFNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "MBLNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "MATNR"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "LGORT"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.RAppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "BWART"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    objFldTab.AppendRow
    objFldTab(objFldTab.RowCount, "FIELDNAME") = "SHKZG"    'FIELD TO DISPLAY
    

    
    If objRfcFunc.Call = False Then
        MsgBox objRfcFunc.Exception
    End If
    
    Dim objDatRec As Object
    Dim objFldRec As Object
    
    For Each objDatRec In objDatTab.Rows
        For Each objFldRec In objFldTab.Rows
            ws.Cells(objDatRec.Index + 1, objFldRec.Index) = Mid(objDatRec("WA"), objFldRec("OFFSET") + 1, objFldRec("LENGTH"))
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```